# Exporting Excel Data into Oracle Table using VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, oracle, excel

I am trying to export an excel file directory into an Oracle table as opposed to looping through the range and executing a lot of insert statements. I would think that there are better ways to accomplish this in .NET but I can't seem to find any other answer besides convert excel to csv & load it using Sql Loader or External Table. Does anyone know a cleaner & more efficient way that looping through the ranges creating & executing insert statements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Oracle's External Tables are actually quite elegant for this (so is SQL loader).  There is a 'depends' argument for either approach.  However, if your looking for a more point and click solution; Oracle has a free tool called [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html) available for download.  It has [support for importing from excel](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12152/dialogs.htm#sthref501).

In addition, there is an entire [forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa;jsessionid=8d92079f30d6f73b0195a610408a90e682595446cd65.e3mSaNmQc3j0ax4NchmOahuKa40?forumID=732&start=0) dedicated to SQL Loader and External Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I recommend that, but you can use ODBC Driver for excel, to see the excel sheets as tables. Then, it is a matter of selecting the data from the excel table and insert it into Oracle table...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think I saw that as one of the search results on Google but I am trying to minimize the number of steps and make it as clean as possible. The ODBC route seems a bit too much. I think based on what I have found, the best option is to save the excel file as CSV, move it to the database server & load it as an external table on Oracle. One would think there would be easier ways to do this but apparently not. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ODI for loading data into oracle tables from excel sheets. But yes it has some issue like more time etc.